# Binding to an Optional value's non-optional property?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm familiar with binding to optional properties in SwiftUI, but how would you bind to a *property* of an optional value? In the example below, `cat` is an optional but `cat.name` is not optional. How would I bind to `cat.name`?

```
import SwiftUI

class Cat {
    var name: String = ""
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
}

class CatManager: ObservableObject {
    var cat: Cat? = Cat(name: "Jiji")
}

struct TestOptional: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var catManager: CatManager
    
    var body: some View {
        
        // Value of optional type 'Cat?' must be unwrapped to refer to member 'name' of wrapped base type 'Cat'
        TextField("Cat's name", text: $catManager.cat.name)
        
        // Value of optional type 'Binding<String?>?' must be unwrapped to a value of type 'Binding<String?>'
        TextField("Cat's name", text: $catManager.cat?.name ?? "")
    }
}

func ??<T>(lhs: Binding<Optional<T>>, rhs: T) -> Binding<T> {
    Binding(
        get: { lhs.wrappedValue ?? rhs },
        set: { lhs.wrappedValue = $0 }
    )
}
```

Compiler error messages are shown in comments above each TextField.

Comment: In the given code there is no reason to declare `cat` optional. And – unrelated to the question – assigning a default value to a property in a class which has an initializer is bad practice. Specify a default value in the `init` method: `init(name: String = "")`.

Comment: This is just a simplified example to illustrate the problem. No, I'm not making a cat manager program :)

Comment: But even in the simplified example there is no reason to declare the property in the manager optional. The design of SwiftUI encourages you to avoid optionals as much as possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, think about what the text field would do when `cat` is nil. There is no `cat`, so there is no `name` for the text field to bind to. If you want the text field to create a new `Cat` with the text field's text, you can add such a property to `CatManager`, and bind to this property instead:

```
var catName: String {
    get { cat?.name ?? "" }
    set {
        if cat == nil {
            cat = Cat(name: newValue)
        } else {
            cat?.name = newValue
        }
    }
}
```

Of course, this is not always possible. `Cat.init` might need to take other parameters. In that case, there is nothing the text field can do, is there?

You can convert `Binding<Cat?>` to `Binding<Cat>?` using one of the `Binding` initialisers. When this binding is nil, there is nothing you can do, so you can just show something else, or disable the text field.

```
if let binding = Binding($catManager.cat) {
    TextField("Cat's name", text: binding.name)
} else {
    Text("There is no cat!")
}
```

or

```
TextField("Cat's name", text: Binding($catManager.cat)?.name ?? .constant(""))
    .disabled(catManager.cat == nil)
```

Other notes:

- `CatManager.cat` should be `@Published` so SwiftUI views can observe changes to it
- `Cat` should be a struct. If you really need it to be a class for some reason, mark both `Cat` and `CatManager` as `@Observable`, and use `@Bindable` to get a `Binding`.

Comment: Thank you, `Binding($catManager.cat)?.name ?? .constant("")` was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

In Swift `Cat` needs to be a struct. In SwiftUI, `CatManager` needs to have an `@Published` array of cats, usually that would be named `CatStore`. Do these 2 things and the optional will be a non issue.